# dynamic model key and value swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing, dynamic, model

I created model like this :

```
struct ExampleData {
var id, value, name, code, description:String?
}
```

and I parse json and put it into model like this :

```
var content = [ExampleData]()
                        content.removeAll()
                        for con in contents {
                            var contentx = ExampleData()
                            for (key, value) in con {
                               print("con key:\(key) with value:\(value)\n")
                                if key == "id" {
                                    contentx.id = value as? String
                                } else if key == "value" {
                                    contentx.value = value as? String
                                } else if key == "name" {
                                    contentx.name = value as? String
                                } else if key == "code" {
                                    contentx.code = value as? String
                                } else if key == "description" {
                                    contentx.description = value as? String
                                }
                                content.append(contentx)
                            }
                        }
```

How to change model become dynamic key and value so I am not use if else again like this :

```
contentx.key = value as? String
```

Note  this is example json that I parse :

```
{
        "content":[
           {
              "id":"X",
              "value":"XXX",
              "name":"",
              "code":"",
              "description":""
           },
           {
              "id":"Y",
              "value":"YYY",
              "name":"",
              "code":"",
              "description":""
           }
        ]
     }
```

Comment: Are you aware of [`Codable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)? It should be trivial to parse JSON into `ExampleData`

Comment: @NewDev, so how to change it become dynamic model key and value?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "become dynamic model key and value". Can you add your JSON into the question? Is it an array like this: `[ { "id": "123", "value": "a", ...}, {...}, ...]` with each object mapping to `ExampleData`?

Comment: @NewDev, this is not create json or parse json. I already parse json, and put into hardcoded model key. so I use if else to add it into model. The question is how to make dynamic model key so I can use contentx.key = value as? String. I saw Codable also use hardcoded model key, so codable is not the correct answer.

Comment: Why use dynamic key? What's your purpose? You might just want to keep `Dictionary` and not custom structs...

Comment: @Larme, because I want to create dynamic form base on model. So this model variable key need dynamic, not hardcoded model var like I wrote.

Comment: So, the JSON you've added to the question can change? i.e. does is sometimes contain different objects? Is that what you mean by dynamic? At the end, you are trying to assign to a specific type. Why not just decode into that type to begin with? Your question isn't clear enough to me around what you mean by dynamic

Comment: @NewDev, dynamic means the form change base model input, you can browse dynamic form swift as keyword to know what is dynamic form. In this question, I already parse JSON and put into hardcoded model variable. What I want is the model variable it self not hardcoded, change variable key same like JSON key that I parse. JSON in this question is just example, and cannot change. If contain different object, I already can parse the key and value.